# particleSystem perform different download from App Store

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, app-store, ccparticlesystem

I developed a game for iPhone versions and tested it on the simulator and actual devices(iphone5/6/6+/ipad) before I launch to App Store. However, when i downloaded my app from the app store, the particle system behave differently only with iPhone 6, 6+. The rate in which the particles execute was so much faster. On my actual test devices the rates was the same across all the iPhone versions. its only after it is downloaded from the app store the rate of execution becomes different.
I use particle designer to generate the plist and below is part of my code:

```
        animationEmitter = [CCParticleSystem particleWithFile:@"columnexpo.plist"];
        [animationEmitter setPosition:ccp(x,y)];
        [self addChild:animationEmitter z:ZValue name:@"boardEmitterAnim"];
```

I used cocos2d v3 for the game. 
Anyone encounter the same problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should test an Instrument/Profile build on your devices - Select ⌘i in Xcode - as this will enable all of the optimisations that will be in place for the build that you send to the App Store.  A standard debug build won't be fully optimised and may have slower performance, as you have found.

Comment: Thank you for your input. However, look like it is not a performance problem, since I have loaded the app to real device (iphone6) and test there is no problem.  In my case, the problem only happen in ccparticlesystem. I don't know what is the different between I load the program from my machine and download from app store.

Comment: Did you load an Instruments build onto your device to test or just a standard debug build?

Comment: No,I just use standard debug build

Comment: Which, if you read my answer, is the problem - Debug builds can run slower than production builds.  An instruments build is the same level of optimisation that you submit to the app store.  Try an instrument build on your actual device and you will probably see that it behaves the same as your app store version

Answer (score 0):

I update the Xcode and the problem is shown in my device now(iphone6)
After checking, look like it relates to the CCAction. I comment the actionSequence function in my code and then the particle rate become normal again. Anyone know the reason?
BTW, I found out another problem that the device cannot show two particle system at the same time, where the device will only show the first child I added. Also this problem only happen in iphone6/6+(real device), simulator shown no problem.

Comment: For more information, the CCAction and the particleSystem in my code are independent, so they should not affect each other.